# issue with dynamoDB scan

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3, dynamodb-queries

We are doing scan on dynamoDB table, sample code as below.
Looks like scan will do scan on full table to fetch the records, Is there any optimized way to update the below code so that it will work on huge datasets.

```
import boto3
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name=region)

table = dynamodb.Table('my-table')

response = table.scan()
data = response['Items']

while 'LastEvaluatedKey' in response:
    response = table.scan(ExclusiveStartKey=response['LastEvaluatedKey'])
    data.extend(response['Items'])
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to optimise it when you don't mention what specific data you want to obtain.

A Scan will always read all the data, if that's not your goal then you can use `GetItem` or `Query` to make it more efficient.

I suggest spending an hour in the documentation to make yourself familiar with the API.

Answer (score -1):

With scan it will always loop the whole data, but at least you can add filters like in the example:

```
response = table.scan(
    FilterExpression=Attr('age').lt(27)
)
items = response['Items']
```

from the [doc](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/dynamodb.html#querying-and-scanning)